# No metrics displayed in cloud console for my api deployed in google cloud endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I have deployed the REST API of my backend in google cloud endpoints. The API works fine, but the cloud console shows no metrics at all. I test the API from different devices every day but cloud console never shows a single request I've done.

I created an openapi.yaml file and deployed it using a gcloud command in cloud shell. Maybe there is something else I haven't done.

Comment: Have you deployed ESP in front of your backend?

Comment: No :/ . I guess I've got to do that first. I didn't even know that existed. Thanks.

Comment: What tutorial were you following, if any? We can see if we can make that step more obvious.